Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform - signInWithEmailAndPassword rate limit from same ip requests
Is there a documented limit on the number of requests to the REST API https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) that can be made from the same IP address?
The question arises from a specific use case where, for a subset of users and a legacy application, the login needs to be managed server-side.
I have made calls to this API (hundreds per hour), and "after a certain point", I received only error responses different from the expected ones.
